# Issue implementing scroll loop effect and rotating div with offsetTop

Tags: javascript, html, css, offset

Im working on a site right now with a scroll loop effect (when you reach the bottom of the page it seamlessly jumps back to the top creating an endless loop). Though I am having an issue trying implement an effect to rotate the individual div's based on their offsetTop.

Here is a fiddle link with the rotate effect working without the scroll loop effect-> https://jsfiddle.net/jacob_truax/bgrkewny/3/

Here is a link to a fiddle with both effects -> https://jsfiddle.net/jacob_truax/b1x4dow7/18/

As you can see in the second fiddle, adding the scroll loop effect while implementing the rotation effect breaks the code. Can someone help me figure this out please?

Here is the js for the broken fiddle

```
const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section")
const divTag = document.querySelector("div.Loop")
const mainTag = document.querySelector("main")

var doc = window.document,
  clones = divTag.querySelectorAll('.is-clone'),
  disableScroll = false,
  scrollHeight = 0,
  scrollPos = 0,
  clonesHeight = 0,
  i = 0;

const addMovement = function() {
  const topViewport = divTag.offsetTop
  const midViewport = topViewport + (divTag.offsetHeight / 2)

  sections.forEach(section => {
    const topSection = section.offsetTop
    const midSection = topSection + (section.offsetHeight / 2)

    const distanceToSection = (midViewport - midSection)
    console.log(distanceToSection)

    const image = section.querySelector(".info")

    image.style.transform = `rotate(${distanceToSection}deg)`
  })
}

addMovement()

function getScrollPos () {
  return (divTag.offsetTop || divTag.scrollTop) - (divTag.clientTop || 0);
}

function setScrollPos (pos) {
  divTag.scrollTop = pos;
}

function getClonesHeight () {
  clonesHeight = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < clones.length; i += 1) {
    clonesHeight = clonesHeight + clones[i].offsetHeight;
  }

  return clonesHeight;
}

function reCalc () {
  scrollPos = getScrollPos();
  scrollHeight = divTag.scrollHeight;
  clonesHeight = getClonesHeight();

  if (scrollPos <= 0) {
    setScrollPos(1); // Scroll 1 pixel to allow upwards scrolling
  }
}

function scrollUpdate () {
  if (!disableScroll) {
    scrollPos = getScrollPos();

    if (clonesHeight + scrollPos >= scrollHeight) {
      // Scroll to the top when you’ve reached the bottom
      setScrollPos(1); // Scroll down 1 pixel to allow upwards scrolling
      disableScroll = true;
    } else if (scrollPos <= 0) {
      // Scroll to the bottom when you reach the top
      setScrollPos(scrollHeight - clonesHeight);
      disableScroll = true;
    }
  }

  if (disableScroll) {
    // Disable scroll-jumping for a short time to avoid flickering
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      disableScroll = false;
    }, 40);
  }
}

function init () {
  reCalc();

  divTag.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollUpdate);
    addMovement()
  }, false);

  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(reCalc);
    addMovement()
  }, false);
}

if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
  init()
} else {
  doc.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false)
}
```

Here is the css

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

body {
  color: #000;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.Loop {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

::scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

section div {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

section img {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The offsetTop property returns the top position (in pixels) relative
>   to the top of the offsetParent element.

Changing line #14 to use scrollTop instead works:

```
  const topViewport = divTag.scrollTop;
```

Comment: Thanks!! Figured it was something simple like this. You wouldn't know how to get rid of that little "glitch" that happens on Hello 1 div when the scollbar jumps back to the top would you?